# Unwanted space with input

Tags: spacing, input

Consider some file `file.tex` only containing the following:

```
\hfill Some text
```

We input this into the main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \input{file}
    
    \hfill Some other text
\end{document}
```

Observe that for the input file, some horizontal space has been added on the right:
[image]

Where does this space come from? How can it be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where the space came from, but ending the line with a comment removes it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \input{file}% <- notice the comment
    
    \hfill Some other text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that end of line is the space

Answer (score 4):

TeX always adds a trailing endline to an `\input` file, which becomes a space in output. The endline after the brace adds another space. Note that tokenization has already been performed, so you get two spaces in output.

On the other hand, `\par` (generated by the following empty line) does `\unskip`, which is able to remove *one* of those spaces and the other one remains.

If you add `\endinput` to your file, this doesn't happen. Note that the suggested `%` only works in the particular case.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname-in.tex}
\hfill Some text\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent\input{\jobname-in}

\noindent\hfill Some other text

\bigskip

\noindent\input{\jobname-in}and other text

\noindent\input{\jobname-in} and other text

\noindent\hfill Some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove the `\endinput`, you get

[image]

where you can clearly see *two* spaces in the middle line of the second group. Here `%` would be of no use.

Alternative to `\endinput` is to do `\input` in the scope of

```
\everyeof{\relax}
```